# Detecting attributes on a class to infer property?

Tags: c#, entity-framework, reflection

I am not too familiar with reflection, however, would it be possible to implement a method that will return an `object` if that class has a property associated with a certain attribute?

I thought it might make this following implementation not being required

```cs
public interface IEntity
{
    object ID { get; }
}
public class Person : IEntity
{
    [Key]
    public int PersonID { get; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public int Age { get; set; }

    object IEntity.ID
    {
        get { return PersonID; }
    }
}
```

So instead of implementing 'IEntity' for every class, you can just do something like this:

```cs
public abstract class EntityBase
{
    public object ID { get { return FindPrimaryKey(); } }

    protected object FindPrimaryKey()
    {
        object key = null;
        try
        {
            //Reflection magic
        }
        catch (Exception) { }
        return key;
    }
}
```

This would just save some time instead of having to go through all code-first generated classes and implementing this small feature.

Comment: I prefer giving all my entities a surrogate key which is an int. 1 abstract EntityBase with just a public int ID. Simple. But if you don't like that then I suggest getting the key from metadata. More info and links here: http://stackoverflow.com/a/19860292/150342 and http://blog.oneunicorn.com/2012/05/03/the-key-to-addorupdate/

Answer (score 2):

Yes, that can definitely be done. Consider the following code:

```
protected object FindPrimaryKey()
{
    object key = null;
    var prop = this.GetType()
                   .GetProperties()
                   .Where(p => Attribute.IsDefined(p, typeof(Key)))
    if (prop != null) { key = prop.GetValue(this); }
    return key;
}
```

However, I would recommend caching that value. Add a private field for the key value:

```
object _keyValue;
```

and then set that:

```
protected void FindPrimaryKey()
{
    var prop = this.GetType()
                   .GetProperties()
                   .Where(p => Attribute.IsDefined(p, typeof(Key)))
    if (prop != null) { _keyValue = prop.GetValue(this); }
}
```

and then return that instead:

```
public object ID { get { return _keyValue; } }
```

Comment: @TheKobra, I'm not sure because I'm not sure what you're talking about. Sorry.

Comment: Sorry for being vague, it was in regard to Entity Framework. I'll just test it and find out :)

Comment: @TheKobra, well I'm glad I could be of assistance!