# About EntityFramework AsNoTracking

Tags: c#, entity-framework

I am using EntityFramework v6.1.2.

I read some articles and know about `AsNoTracking` extension.

When `AsNoTracking` is called, it means that if the entity is not attached, the context and the entity updated "*should fail*".

But I have tried and updated successfully, my code is in below:

```
private readonly DemoObjectContext _objectContext = new DemoObjectContext();
var order = _objectContext.Orders.AsNoTracking().FirstOrDefault(x => x.Id == 1);(1 is the primary key)

order.OrderStatus = OrderStatus.Processing; // change the orderstatus
                //_objectContext.Set<Order>().Attach(order);
                _objectContext.Entry(order).State = EntityState.Modified;
                _objectContext.SaveChanges();
```

Is something wrong or did *EntityFramework(6.1.2)* changed something?

Please help me

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No issues with EF. It works because `Entry` attaches the entity to the context.

[See here for more details.](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-US/data/jj592676)

[And on this SO specifically about `Entry`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15045763/what-does-the-dbcontext-entry-do)