# EF Core misses changes made during SaveChangesAsync()

Tags: c#, .net, .net-core, entity-framework-core

I'm calling `DbContext.SaveChangesAsync()` to save my objects to the database. This takes about 120 ms.

If an event changes an tracked object's property during this time, this change is neither directly saved to database nor tracked by the EF Core ChangeTracker to save it later.

That means, that if I call `DbContext.SaveChangesAsync()` later again, the new property value is still not saved to the database because the EF Core ChangeTracking doesn't see this change.

I was expecting that `DbContext.SaveChangesAsync()` can't save changes to the database that are made during the operation. But I was expecting that the EF Core ChangeTracker would track this change correctly to make it possible to later save it to the database.

Comment: Do you use transactions?

Comment: Are you sure you are tracking it? you should try to see if that change is actually really being tracked by looking at the change tracker.

Comment: Because `.SaveChanges` is effectively `.DetectChanges` => sql => `.AcceptAllChanges`.

Comment: I'm not using transactions (beside the automatic ones) and I'm shure the object itself is tracked. If i do some changes to it later, they're correctly detected. @JeremyLakeman I think that's my problem. The SQL operation between `.DetectChanges` and `.AcceptAllChanges` takes some time. And all changes made during this are accepted without beeing saved.

Comment: How do you change the properties? More details of your code should be helpful.

Answer (score 3):

One of possible solutions is to mark the object as **Modified** explicitly. There is an `Entry()` method to obtain an `EntityEntry` for the object you want to modify, and then calling the **EntityEntry.State** property to set its state to **Modified**:

```
db.Entry(yourEntity).State = EntityState.Modified;
```

**Note**: some more details can be found by the [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15045763/what-does-the-dbcontext-entry-do) and [documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/change-tracking/explicit-tracking).

Multiple `DbContext` instances might also be used to switch between them for such cases as EF Core implements [optimistic concurrency](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/saving/concurrency?tabs=data-annotations), however IMO it might cause more problems than benefits without deep understanding. So everyone should use it carefully as it can lead to unexpected behaviour and issues.

Comment: Thanks. Also if I mark it as *Modified* explicitly, the changes seem to get accepted without beeing saved so that the object isn't marked as modified aftewards anymore. See above comments from @Jeremy and me.

Comment: @joru1407 There is a possibility to handle the ChangeTracker manually as well: `context.ChangeTracker.AutoDetectChangesEnabled = false;` in the beginning of method, mark the Entity as modified explicitly, and turn AutoDetection on back after `SaveChanges()`. Please, try it and LMK if it helps. I didn't test it before, however it potentially might fix the gap between Detecting and Accepting.